# Ruby on rails: singular resource and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, router, form-for, singular

I want user to work with only one order connected to user's session. So I set singular resource for order

routes.rb:

```
resource :order
```

views/orders/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

But when I open the new order page I get an error:

```
undefined method `orders_path`
```

I know, that I can set `:url => order_path` in `form_for`, but what is the true way of resolving this collision?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get why you don't use singular for your resource

Comment: Because rails guide advice to use plural form of controller.  But in singular form of controller exists same bug...

Comment: If you just have a singular nested resource that is giving you problems, you can use `form_for [@user, :subscription, @payment]` to generate paths for `user_subscription_payment_path(@user, @payment)` with paths like `action="/users/21/subscription/payments/29"`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is [a bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769). You'll have to set the url like you mention.

```
= form_for @order, :url => order_path do |f|
```

Note that this will properly route to `create` or `update` depending on whether `@order` is persisted.

---

**Update**

There's another option now. You can add this to your routes config:

```
resolve("Order") { [:order] }
```

Then when the `polymorphic_url` method is given an object with class name "Order" it will use `[:order]` as the url component instead of calling `model_name.route_key` as described in [jskol's answer](/a/16229154/135346).

This has the limitation that it cannot be used within scopes or namespaces. You can route a namespaced model at the top level of the routes config:

```
resolve('Shop::Order') { [:shop, :order] }
```

But it won't have an effect on routes with extra components, so

```
url_for(@order)           # resolves to shop_order_url(@order)
url_for([:admin, @order]) # resolves to admin_shop_orders_url(@order) 
                          #        note plural 'orders' ↑
                          #        also, 'shop' is from module name, not `resolve` in the second case
```

Comment: Rails' issues have been moved from Lighthouse to Github. Here's the issue in Github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769

Comment: currently, this is a solution https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769#issuecomment-9556381

Comment: Still an issue in late 2016. Just everyone is updated.. ;)

Answer (score 58):

### Where does that magic path come from?

It took me a lot of tracing but I ultimately found that the url_for determines the path for your model using the `polymorphic_path` method defined in **ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes**. `polymorphic_path` ultimately gets the automagic path for your model by calling something along the lines of:

```
record.class.model_name.route_key
```

I'm simplifying slightly but this is basically it.  If you have an array (e.g. `form_for[@order, @item]`) the above is called on each element and the results are joined with `_`.

The `model_name` method on your Class comes from **ActiveRecord::Naming**.

```
module ActiveModel
  ...
  module Naming
    ...
    def model_name
      @_model_name ||= begin
        namespace = self.parents.detect do |n|
          n.respond_to?(:use_relative_model_naming?) && 
                                                 n.use_relative_model_naming?
        end
        ActiveModel::Name.new(self, namespace)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### How can I change it?

Fortunately **ActiveModel::Name** precalculates all values including route_key, so to override that value all we have to do is change the value of the instance variable.

For the `:order` resource in your question:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  model_name.instance_variable_set(:@route_key, 'order')
  ...
end

# new.html.erb
<%= form_for @order do |f| # Works with action="/order" %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Try it out!

Comment: @aidan thanks! The other answer had already been accepted for awhile when I encountered this issue myself.

Comment: That's a lot of investigating for a super rad answer. way to go.

Comment: This is a ninja answer.

Comment: This is the only easy solution for a polymorphic singular resource where you can't explicitly set the url option.

Comment: All attributes on the ActiveName class (route_key, param_key, cache_key, etc) are RW, so you don't need to use instance_variable_set (which is pretty intrusive and not supposed to be used in regular code). This works:

`class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  model_name.param_key = 'order'
end`