# Rails has_one new action going to wrong route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, associations, has-one

When I click the 'New Schedule Status' button on the 'Project' show page, but the route that the error shows me is plural, when it should be singular. Here's my code:

```
# project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :schedule_status
end

# schedule_status.rb
class ScheduleStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

# schedule_statuses_controller.rb
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @schedule_status = @project.build_schedule_status
end

# routes.rb
resources :projects do
  resource :schedule_status
end

# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for [@project, @schedule_status] do |f| %>
  ...
```

The error informs me that my `form_for` line is incorrect. It seems like my instance variables are setup correctly, but the error is:

```
undefined method `project_schedule_statuses_path` for ...
```

Any idea why the route it's attempting to access is **plural**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. form_for looks for the plural version of the object. However since you've declared a singular resource :schedule_status, the path helper method is never created.

To get around this you should use :url parameter for form_for.

Look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736759/ruby-on-rails-singular-resource-and-form-for) for more clarity.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I've been searching for this, but somehow I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug it is a **feature** (ticket closed as won't fix):

rails issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769

summary quote:

> the error has been around for a long while however a clean solution
>   doesn't readily represent itself. The polymorphic_url helper has no
>   'intelligence' in how it operates - it has no information about what
>   you've declared as resources in your routes.rb. All it has to go on it
>   the name of the model and how that maps to the named url helpers.
>
> The problem is there is no easy way to discern whether a model maps
>   to a singular or a regular resource url. Checking for the presence of
>   a collection url doesn't work as the resource may have been specified
>   with :except => :index and trying to rescue route generation errors
>   doesn't work because passing an instance to a singular resource url
>   helper will generate a url with the format set to the id and no
>   exception.

rails issue closed in favour of the previous:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4978

**conclusion**:

> in such cases you're supposed to give the url. url_for cannot reflect
>   on routes to see if that's a resource or not.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a feature, but more of a "Not sure how to implement this"

Comment: btw, I suggested a solution, see the issue