# form_for nested resource (singular) not using correct path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm probably doing something stupid, but...

app/model/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :totem
```

config/routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resource :totem
end
```

app/controllers/totems_controller.rb:

```
class TotemsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter do
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def new
        @totem = @user.build_totem
    end

end
```

app/views/totems/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @totem] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Then, when I navigate to `/users/123/totem/new`, I get  the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_totems_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9d3c843b00>:0x007f9d3bb6dd68>):
```

But because I'm using `resource :totem` instead of `resources :totems` in routes.rb, the path helper it should be using is `user_totem_path`. Why isn't it trying to use the correct path helper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on rails: singular resource and form\_for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736759/ruby-on-rails-singular-resource-and-form-for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found my answer in another question: [Ruby on rails: singular resource and form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736759/ruby-on-rails-singular-resource-and-form-for#16229154)

app/models/totem.rb:

```
class Totem < ActiveRecord::Base
    model_name.instance_variable_set :@route_key, 'totem'
    belongs_to :user
end
```

(not sure why this Q&A didn't appear in my earlier searches...)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use

```
form_for @totem, :url => user_totem_path(@user) do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
resource :totem
```

it should be

```
resources :totem
```

Comment: I was using `resources` before, but I'd prefer to use `resource` because each user has only one totem, and `resource` generates slightly neater URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why too. I used this way (providing a url to form_for) to bypass the problem

```
<%= form_for [@user, @totem], :as => :totem, :url => user_totem_path do |f| %>
```

Also, some research from google find out that there's a bug report in earlier rails. But i am not sure whether it's been fixed or not in the latest rails. Here is the link if you would like to do more research

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/267